# Referencing Subfigure in Subfloat

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I want to reference a subfigure like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
     \subfloat[A subcaption.]{\label{figure:subfigure1}\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo}}
     \caption{A caption.}
     \label{figure:figure1}
\end{figure}

\noindent
Subfigure \ref{figure:subfigure1}, Figure \ref{figure:figure1}.

\end{document}
```

However, I am getting a "Reference undefined" warning and the output is:

[image]

When I am using

```
\usepackage{subfig}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

the output is as expected (references are all found).

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I checked the package versions. Indeed, they are old:

```
Package: subcaption 2008/08/31 v1.0b 
Package: caption 2009/10/09 v3.1k caption kernel (AR)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your first MWE doesn't compile for me; `\subfloat` is not from the `subcaption` package. Instead, use `\begin{subfigure}{<width>}<Figure code>\caption{<caption>}\label{<label>}\end{subfigure}` and all will be good :)

Comment: silly question, why not use `subfig` then if it works? I don't know `subcaption`, so the syntax may be correct, but by the look of it the syntax you are using is that of `subfig`.

Comment: @cmhughes Thank you! Yes this would work, however I am using subfloats for a reason (to span a figure over multiple pages using continuedfloat).

Comment: @ArTourter Cannot use subfig since it doesn't play nicely with hyperref.

Comment: @ArTourter Yes, might be wrong about that, I don't have a MWE. In the example above,  `hyperref` works properly. Still it doesn't in my main document. A major benefit of using `subcaption` is IMHO that I can use both `subfigure` and `subfloat`. It would therefore be nice to solve the issue at hand.

Comment: @Tobold I cannot see any references to `subfloat` in the `subcaption` documentation. `\continuedfloat` is provided by the caption package and does not seem to have anything to with the usage of `\subfloat`: it is used after a `\begin{figure}` or `\begin{table}`.

Comment: @ArTourter I appreciate your help. In my case, `subfloat` seems to be defined in `subcaption`. Maybe I am using one of those very early versions Axel is referring to. Probably it is also why the MWE didn't work for @cmhughes. Should have updated before posting here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `\subfloat` was indeed defined in very early versions of the `subcaption` package but this was never a documented feature (and has proven to be a very bad idea anyway since it was not 100% compatible with `\subfloat` offered by the `subfig` package). As equivalent the `subcaption` package offers the (well documented) command `\subcaptionbox` with a slightly different (and enhanced) syntax and behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
     \subcaptionbox{A subcaption.\label{figure:subfigure1}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo}}
     \caption{A caption.}
     \label{figure:figure1}
\end{figure}

\noindent
Subfigure \ref{figure:subfigure1}, Figure \ref{figure:figure1}.

\end{document}
```

(Please note when using `\subcaptionbox` the `\label` needs to be placed inside the caption argument, not inside the content argument.)

Comment: This seems to work. Didn't know about `\subcaptionbox`, thank you!

Comment: BTW: `\subcaptionbox` has some additional optional parameters, better take a (short) look at the `subcaption` package documentation.